# Python/pandas: weighted mean of column values using dates difference

Tags: csv, pandas, mean, weighted

I have a dataframe, which I import using `read_csv()`, whose two columns are dates ('StartDate' and 'EndDate'), with date format dd/mm/yyyy. Another column contains possible daily prices ('Price').

An (very small) extract looks like:

```
DateStart  DateEnd     Price
01/01/2015 31/01/2015  100
01/01/2015 02/01/2015  10
```

I need to compute the average daily price, that is here: `(31*100+2*10)/(31+2)`, using the number of days as weights.

How can I get the number of days between the start and end date? So far as I read, this formatting dd/mm/yyyy will not be recognized as a date?

Once I have this number of days in the interval, how to calculate a weighted mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import datetime, pandas as pd, numpy as np
```

1. First, define the date format you have in your csv

```py
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

2. Then read it and specify the date columns

```py
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", parse_dates=['DateStart','DateEnd'], date_parser=dateparse)
```

3. And here is your result:

```py
number_of_days = ( (df.DateEnd - df.DateStart + datetime.timedelta(1) ) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D'))

result = ( number_of_days * df.Price ).sum() / number_of_days.sum()

print result
```

Voilà

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your solution almost works, but not fully. Indeed, there can be some kind of overflow by calculating `( (df.DateEnd - df.DateStart + datetime.timedelta(1))* df.Price)` whose result is here a number of days. Example, if 170 days and price is 619, I get 105230 as result, which is ok, but if price is 640, I get -104024 as a result! Something should be changed to specify that Days*Price is unitless. Is it possible?

Comment: As a result, I can get some negative average values for positive prices.

Comment: @Elsalex You are right, I just made an edit, it should work, let me know.

Comment: Works fine now! Merci beaucoup !

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `dayfirst=True` to `to_datetime` to parse those dates.  Then you can calculate the difference and calculate the weighted average.

```
In [82]: for c in ['DateStart','DateEnd']:
    ...:     df[c] = pd.to_datetime(df[c], dayfirst=True)

In [87]: df['day_diff'] = (df['DateEnd'] - df['DateStart']).dt.days + 1


In [88]: df['Price'].dot(df['day_diff']) / df['day_diff'].sum()
Out[88]: 94
```